# PBW, or Oxyclean Free, that is the question

Tags: cleaning, oxiclean, pbw, cleaners

Ok so it gone like this :

**Me** : I red on some forums that I could save a lot of money by switching from PBW to Oxyclean Free. Do you want to go to Walmart tonight?

**Him** : You mean the cloth cleaner? Hum, there's no way it's food grade.

**Me** : I don't think PBW is neither.

**Him** : Well, I don't think you're right. Like dish soap, PBW must be somewhat similar in terms of food regulation. And I don't find the full chemistry compounds of Oxyclean. Also, it's a really strong stuff, it may detach some  micro particles of plastic off your bucket.

---

So I'm asking you guys.. is it safe or not? Should I play safe and buy that expensive pbw?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

PBW is completely safe.  I used it for years before switching to Craftmeister cleaners, which are much more effective.  PBW works a little better than Oxi, and Craftmeister works significantly better than PBW.  But all 3 are safe and effective.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using PBW, One Step and Star-San for almost 20 years mostly for winemaking but I also make a lot of homebrew. PBW is great for getting rid of tough stains. When I clean my wine hoses, it really gets the stains out, but I don't think it's all that great on killing the bad stuff.

One Step is supposed not that great at sanitizing stuff. Hard to clean stains get oxidized and turn brown but don't really get removed.

Star-San is great for sanitizing equipment with no rinse, but does not do a great job on hard to clean stains.

What I do for deep cleaning is use PBW to get the big stains and then rinse with hot water and then Star-San to sanitize with no rinse. For clean equipment I just go straight to Star-San and no rinse.

For a complete rundown of cleaning agents, you should [read this](https://www.bayareamashers.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Comparison-of-cleaners-and-sanitizers.pdf)

Comment: one comment...we sanitize things, not sterilize them.  That's a different level than what we do.  Star San is also not a cleaner and should not be used as one.

Comment: Who said sterilize? ;-)

Comment: well, you did before you edited the post!  :)  And Star San still isn't a cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Oxiclean countless times. The regular version and the free with no off flavors! Be sure to rinse well and you will be fine. If used in conjunction with hard water it can cause an oxide layer to build up on stainless over time. However this can be removed by passivation with an acid cleaner such as StarSan. I use Oxiclean most of the time but on the real tough jobs I use PBW which is way more expensive.